# how to use scipy.stats.kstest/basic questions about Kolmogorov–Smirnov test

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

The help link is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html
I can compute the  ks-test value now,but I do not understand it.
The code is as below.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
sample =np.loadtxt('mydata',delimiter=",",usecols=(2,),unpack=True)
print stats.kstest(sample, 'poisson', args=(1,))
```

Q1 
If the reference distribution is constant,what word can replace 'poisson' above? 
Q2 
what is the meaning of `args=(1,)`? 
Q3 
If anybody is interested in ks-test,here is the wiki link. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test 
Can we write our own python code to practice? We can get *max(D)* easily,but how to get *Pr(k<=x)* in the link? What is the relation between *max(D)* and *Pr(k<=x)*?

Comment: By 'constant' do you mean a uniform reference distribution?

Comment: yes,'uniform' works.Q1 solved.Thanks.

Comment: Q3 is probably more suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks.I will put it there.

Answer (score 8):

Q2: look at this, I have a array called `x1`

```
>>> stats.kstest(x1, 'norm')
(0.50018855199491585, 0.0)
>>> stats.kstest(x1, stats.norm.cdf)
(0.50018855199491585, 0.0)
>>> stats.kstest(x1, stats.norm.cdf, args=(0,))
(0.50018855199491585, 0.0)
>>> stats.kstest(x1, stats.norm.cdf, args=(2,))
(0.84134903906580316, 0.0)
>>> stats.kstest(x1, 'norm', args=(2,))
(0.84134903906580316, 0.0)
```

If you pass the name of distribution, i.e., `'norm'`, what actually get passed to `kstest` is the standard distribution `cdf`. By standard, it means for normal distribution having mean==0 and sigma=1.
If you don't want the standard `cdf`, you can pass additional parameters to `cdf` using `args=()`. In this case I only passed the mean. That is, we testing the difference between `x1` and a normal distribution with mean==2 and sigma=1.

Q3: The short answer is, yes. But, why reinventing the wheel? If you want to know how it is implemented, just check the source code. It is in `your_package_folder\scipy\stats\stats.py`, line 3292.

Comment: Thanks.Trying different values is a good method.I am trying "uniform" but  still confused very much.You know the meaning of the two output values?

Comment: @questionhang, the first value is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic, the second one is p value (which is calculated based on KS statistic). Smaller p value indicates more significantly the null hypothesis (that `x1` is normal distributed in this example) is to be rejected.

Comment: Please let me put my original question here.I have a time series data set of photon arrival times from a detector and need to know whether the arrival time is uniform.Qa:I should do a one-sample or two-sample k-s test?I have put it at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71144/what-is-the-definition-of-one-sample-kolmogorovsmirnov-test/71213?iemail=1&noredirect=1#71213 Qb:You know the mathematical expression of the p-value and test statistic?As I know,NumericalRecipe and wiki are the most detailed materials.

Comment: Answered there as well. I think 2-sample KS test is not appropriate.